# A Physics Problem Involving Refraction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, reflection, refraction, intensity

[image]

I'm not sure how to solve this problem. I've considered using Malus' law, but then I don't know what theta is, preventing me from solving this problem.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, you have to know about the Brewster's angle and take into account that polarizing sunglasses have vertical polarization.